# Debug Watch Expression: How to customize the display of an object in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, debugging, watch, debuggervisualizer

In Eclipse's watch window ("Expressions"), is there a way to have eclipse interpret the contents of a class/structure, rather than having to open the tree?  Currently the "value" for any class/structure is `{...}`, and opening it consumes multiple lines in the Expressions window.

i.e, suppose I have a class complex with real and imag.

```
class complex_t {
    double real, imag;
}
```

Is there an XML file somewhere in eclipse to indicate that complex_t should display the values for .real and .imag instead of {...}?  I've been searching on Visualizers, but I think that is something else.

Visual Studio, had this functionality say 10 years ago or so and I found it very handy (autoexp.dat).  I don't use VS anymore but I think it might now be called Native Visualizer (NatVis).  I even found that that Boost provides these XML files to visualizing objects in their library. (https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/wiki/DebuggerVisualizers).  No mention of Eclipse, which is an indication that the answer is no.

---

Edit: I'm looking for a solution for C/C++ (specifically for Code Composer Studio actually).

Below [josivan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1364499/josivan) does have a solution for Java though.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to show details during debug you can do something like

Window > Preferences > Java > Debug > Detail Formatters

Click in Add, Choose your class. In area "Detail formatter code snippet" you define what you want. For example:

[image]

```
return "[r: " + real + ", i: " + imag + "]";
```

On debug Perpective you can see details of your class.

Take a look in the imagem bellow.

[image]

In eclipse [help](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fpreferences%2Fjava%2Fdebug%2Fref-detail_formatters.htm) you can get more details. And [here](http://www.robertwloch.net/2012/01/eclipse-tips-tricks-detail-formatter/) are a good article about it.

Comment: That looks pretty good for Java.  I don't have that option in C though... +1, but I'm going to reword the question for C.  Thanks though.

Comment: If you are using the eclipse for C development. I believe you can do the same and get the same result.

Comment: I've looked all over the debug tabs, and for anything named "Formatter".  Only found the code style formatter.